# Passing object from PHP to Mysql Stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, object

Scenario :- I have to call MYSQL stored procedure from PHP and do some operations (around 15 commands) on the database.

Problem :- I have to call stored procedure with 36 parameters. Lot of parameters. I don't think it is a good idea to pass these many individual parameters and even heard passing individual parameters increases network traffic.

Looking for :- I created a Data Object at PHP side and is there any way I can create similar kind of Object in MYSQL and pass this object as a parameter and extract the data from the object in MYSQL stored procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass objects between different programs. Only variables of scalar type can be passed.
You can use some *serialization* mechanism to convert your data array into string and back.

The easiest serialization mechanism is split-based, we all used in our first gueastbook script :)
There are also `json encoding` and PHP `serialize()` among widely used ones.

Comment: Thanks for quick response . I can serialize in PHP and again unserialize in PHP . But here I want to pass the serialized object as a parameter to MYSQL stored procedure and want to unserialize in MYSQL.

Comment: I know that you  want to pass the serialized object as a parameter to MYSQL stored procedure. So, you have to invent some unserialize function for your stored procedure. Or google it. It can be not php serialize format though. I don't see much problem with passing all parameters though. You can iinsert it into temporary table and then select from within procedure

Comment: Thanks for throwing me the ideas . Now I am clear on this and going to invent some unserialize function for my stored procedure. I don't think It is a big deal now. Once again thanks for your advise